# ios8: Plain label font gets mixed up when replacing text

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uistoryboard

I got a normal UILabel with standard text set in storyboard, depending on various choices I am replacing the string. Obviously iOS then gets all mixed up with finding the corresponding characters for German special characters ä/ö/ß in the used font?!

[image: first rendering of the Label with standard values from storyboard]
[image: rendered Label after resetting the String]

Did anyone experience this problem yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am already self-answering my question, as it is a very stupid mistake(blaming it on the long working hours ^^) - but I think for beginners it might not be that obvious.

You gotta replace your special characters in the string with escaped unicode representations, then everything is rendered perfectly fine. :)

So for German that would be:

```
Ö -> replace with: \u{00D6}
ö -> replace with: \u{00F6}
Ä -> replace with: \u{00c4}
ä -> replace with: \u{00e4}
Ü -> replace with: \u{00dc}
ü -> replace with: \u{00FC}
ß -> replace with: \u{00df}
```